# How to implement testing on ios project that relies on firebase API's

Tags: swift, unit-testing, firebase, xctest

I have a project that uses FirebaseAuth, Firebase Database and Firebase Storage. The project is well advanced and needs to implement automated testing.
I have recently studied unit testing using ios XCTests. I understood basically how the native use of unit testing works and through the use of Mocks (Cuckoo specifically).

I arranged my code by removing dependency injections and something like that to prepare to implement the tests.
My question is that I needed to do tests like:

"When I perform a certain action on a ViewController, I wanted to check if it is saving a certain object in a Firebase Database collection (or mock), on the correct path."

Or better,

When registering a new user in the database (*["name": "Mike", "email":"mike@email.com", "gender":"male"]*), I would like to verify that it was actually saved in the path "*/users/{mikeId}/{mike}*".

I do not know if I was very clear, but I have doubts about how to test this kind of thing. Would I have to test the functions of my DataManager that do operations in the database? Create mocks that get this value and create a sort of fake database locally?

Comment: You may not need any real advanced testing; Almost all Firebase calls have an either optional and/or required closure to process returned data or report errors. If you impement those within your app, you will have real-time feedback and if, per your question, a write to a location fails, that closure will be notified of the failure and presented with an error code that contains info about the failure.